# How and where to create a prefix key for memcache?

Tags: caching

I am up to here in drupal documentation :

> Start at least one instance of memcached on your server.
>   Edit settings.php to make memcache the default cache class, for example:
>     $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
>     $conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
>     $conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'something_unique';

Why do I need a memcache key prefix if have only one database? Anyway where and how do I set it?

Answer (score 6):

All those settings are added to *settings.php*

usually *sites/default/settings.php*

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'k1';
// Use database for cache_form
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
```

You only need a memcache key prefix if you're using memcache with more than one site on that server. Adding a short key, e.g `$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'k1';` is good practice.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use a prefix and also used the following which has it up and running:include_once('./includes/cache.inc');
include_once('./sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc');
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';

Comment: If you have a larger site and don't want AJAX or form cache functionality to break, add this as well:
`$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';`

Comment: @StevenLinn, thanks, `cache_form` exclusion rule added for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Drupal 8: (also in settings.php)

`$settings['memcache']['key_prefix'] = 'something_unique';`